# File upload using cordova-plugin-file-transfer not working on Android, only on iOS

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

Does anyone have any idea what might be the problem? For the last weeks i've been trying to figure out why my code works only on iOS and not on Android devices. Any idea would be highy appreciated since i run out of options.

On the android device it shows to send the file but on the server i don't recive any informations (nor the picture neither the rest of the parameters). On the other hand on iOS all works just fine, and the server also.

My code:

home.html:

> ```
> <button ion-button color="dark" (click)="takePhoto()">Open camera </button>
> <img [src]="imageURL" *ngIf="imageURL" />
> <br>imageURL={{imageURL}}
> <br><button ion-button color="dark" (click)="upload()">Upload</button>
> ```

home.ts:

```
@Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    imageURL: any;
    myInput: string;
    cameraUrl: string;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    }

   takePhoto(){
       Camera.getPicture().then((imageData) => {
            this.imageURL = imageData;
       }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
       });
   }
   upload(){
       var ft = new Transfer();
       var options = {
       fileKey: 'file',
       fileName: 'filename.jpg',
       params:{operatiune:'uploadpoza'}
   }
   ft.upload(this.imageURL,encodeURI("https://www.myserver.com/test.php"),options)
       .then((data) => {
            // success
            alert("image send:"+this.imageURL);
        }, (err) => {
          // error
          alert("err: "+JSON.stringify(err));
        })
    }
}
```

I've checked the errors in two ways:

Case 1:

I have 2 alerts in my uploaded code:
a. a message in case of success: alert("image send:"+this.imageURL);
b. a message for error: alert("err: "+JSON.stringify(err));

In my case, I noticed that only the first message appears, the one where
the code is executed correctly.

Case 2:

I've connected my phone through cable to the laptop.
To launch the app I typed in "Node.js-Command-Prompt" the command "ionic run
Android". 
I've opened Chrome browser and typed in the address bar
"chrome://inspect/#devices". Then select "INSPECT-option" for my app and
popup the console. The console didn't show any error.
Is this the right way to test it, or should I try something different?

I printed the object "data" received in case of success for "ft.upload"
function. The result are:

```
data.response=
data.responseCode=200
data.bytesSent=411240
```

For me this means that information is sent to the server.

One more thing:
- I've run different kinds of tests: sending information to both  servers
with HTTPS and HTTP
- I've tried adding the trustAllHosts=true and in another test
trustAllHosts=false

And every time the same problem: works on iOS but fails on android

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try setting `chunkedMode` false in the config.

```
   var options = {
   chunkedMode: false,
   fileKey: 'file',
   fileName: 'filename.jpg',
   params:{operatiune:'uploadpoza'}
```

Comment: Perfect, it's working. Thank you so much. This setting solved my problem and ended a long series of searches and  tests.

Comment: You are my hero!

Comment: `chunkedMode: true,` has been working all along, but since yesterday images aren't working, but this solved the issue, had to update the app.

Comment: setting the **chunkedMode** to **false** didn't help me. I have an app in production and I need to fix this ASAP. file uploads work fine on my local dev machine, obviously, because they're posted over HTTP. but when I target our production server over HTTPS file uploads fail with this error: **[boringssl_session_write] SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL: operation failed externally to the library**. I'm getting this in the XCode's Debug Console. Can someone please clarify this. This is a terrible issue. I'm not even sure what's going wrong, been struggling for hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var onUploadSuccess = function (r) {
     clearCache();
     alert(JSON.stringify(r));      
}

var onUploadFailed = function (error) {
     alert(JSON.stringify(r));
}

var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";

var params = new Object();
params.action = "some value";//=== if u want to send some other parameters

options.params = params;
options.chunkedMode = false;

var ft = new FileTransfer();

ft.upload(imageURI, SITE_URL+"upload.php", onUploadSuccess, onUploadFailed, options);
```